# Table Layout with fixed textview

Tags: android, tablelayout

i need help on how to make fixed textview size in table layout.
say if the text on it exceeds its size, i want the text on it to go to next line, and other textviews' height on the same row will get stretched as well.

i'm using layout_weight to determine the size of textview, but problems come when the text on it exceeds its size. the table layout will become all messed up.

i'm trying to use 'dp' to make the size fixed, but i'm afraid the size will not fit the size of larger screen.

can anyone help on this? thanks in advance.

i'm using a scrollview on other rows but header row.

edit : changed the description, what i want is the text will go to next line if the text is too long and other textviews on same row will get stretched as well.

Comment: you can try android:singleLine="true"
and android:ellipsize="end"             
    android:maxLines="1"

Comment: Just a note: [`android:singleLine` is deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine); you should instead be using `android:lines="1"` or an `inputType` parameter.

Comment: im sorry for the confusion. i've changed my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:stretchColumns` property for table-layout. so it will stretch your column and then in the child views of the table-row you can set the weight so that you can make all column with same width.

Here is a sample code.

```
 <TableLayout
android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Number of Years of Installation"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNumberOfYearsOfInstallation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />
</TableRow>
```